# Android Resources$NotFoundException when inflating activity from library project

Tags: android, android-studio, mupdf

What could cause this problem when I added the MuPDF library to my project.

This is the error log:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: ch.my.app, PID: 18899
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ch.my.app/com.artifex.mupdflib.MuPDFActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File  from drawable resource ID #0x7f0d000f: .xml extension required
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3119)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3218)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:198)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1676)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6837)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
         Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File  from drawable resource ID #0x7f0d000f: .xml extension required
            at android.content.res.Resources.twLoadColorStateList(Resources.java:4013)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:3943)
            at android.content.res.Resources.getColor(Resources.java:2072)
            at com.artifex.mupdflib.MuPDFActivity.onCreate(MuPDFActivity.java:295)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6500)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1120)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3072)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3218) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:198) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1676) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6837) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

I am adding MuPDF library as module, this is the settings.gradle

```
include ':app'
include ':library_MuPDF'
```

And the build.gradle for module app contains:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 23
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
}
```

And the project gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Android studio is not showing any problems.
This is the code where it is crashing:

```
getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.actionbar_background_dark));
```

When I disable this, the problem is when inflating:

```
mButtonsView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.buttons, null);
```

This is the inflating error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ch.app.app, PID: 3283
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ch.app.app/com.artifex.mupdflib.MuPDFActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2484)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2544)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1394)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5845)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at com.artifex.mupdflib.MuPDFActivity.makeButtonsView(MuPDFActivity.java:1091)
        at com.artifex.mupdflib.MuPDFActivity.createUI(MuPDFActivity.java:587)
        at com.artifex.mupdflib.MuPDFActivity.onCreate(MuPDFActivity.java:473)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6248)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1125)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2437)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2544) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1394) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5845) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
```

Everything what I checked looks correctly, I cleaned the project, did clean install of the app, removed all other apps using this library and this problem is still happening.

Where could I look for some another possible problems?

Thanks

Comment: Do you think the line that says `.xml extension required` means anything?

Comment: As I responded to the answer below, the library itself is working completely fine with sample project (https://github.com/joniks/Android-MuPDF). So the xml extension is at its place like it should be. Even the Android Studio doesn't have any problems with finding in (cmd-click is transferring me to the correct XML file with correct color list). The question was not about correctness of the code, sorry, I should have mentioned that. Or if you meant something different, please, let me know.

Comment: The stacktrace has a line that says `Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File  from drawable resource ID #0x7f0d000f: .xml extension required`

Comment: Yes, I see that. That's the result of some problem. But I don't know what is causing it, because the drawable is OK as well as 2nd example where the inflater has problems with layout where the layout is completely fine (because it's the same as in the sample which is working, the module was imported from working library). I really don't know what are you trying to suggest.

Comment: Do you have `res/values/colors` or `res/values/colors.xml`? The error seems to point at the fact that one of your files does not have an XML extension

Comment: And the other error says there is something wrong with Line #14 of `buttons.xml`, so maybe you should add that to your question.

Comment: https://github.com/joniks/Android-MuPDF/blob/master/library/res/values/colors.xml this is the file (it has the XML extension). As I said, in sample it's working with the same library (and the Activity is inside the library, so there is no change in that). And the line #14 is also completely fine. The files are there and the code is correct, it's just looking like that they are not inside deployed APK or something in that sense. That's what I can't find out

Comment: Are you saying you are able clone that Github repo and run it, or not?

Comment: Also, I just looked at that Github link, and the project doesn't even have Gradle support, so I'm not sure what you really expected to happen by using `compile project` and `include` it from Gradle

Comment: Yes, when I clone it and import it to Android Studio (the gradle is generated by AS)  that's working without any problems. The problem started when I imported (already with gradle) to my regular project this library as a module. The AS created the gradle fine, they are in the sample as 2 separate modules (the same as I am using in my app).

Comment: That Github project doesn't use the default format that Android Studio uses for Gradle, so can you please add the `build.gradle` files that it generated for you?

Comment: I will put them here tomorrow, I am not near the computer right now. But everything important is already in the post - the include and compile. And that's the same in my project as in the sample.

Comment: I've added the Gradle files, but as I said the important things were already in the post.

Comment: As I suspected, the `sourceSets` are not configured in the Gradle file(s). The defaults are to look for code and resources in the `src/main/java` and `src/main/res` directories, so if a resource can't be found, then that's a reasonable explanation it wasn't compiled into the apk

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109639/discussion-between-tunerx-and-cricket-007).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your library project has the color.xml file within the res/values folder

Comment: The library is from this source https://github.com/joniks/Android-MuPDF and there is sample project which is using this library. Therefore, I strongly believe that this is not the core of the problem (because the sample project with exactly the same lib with the same code is working completely fine). There has to be some setting or flag which is wrong, the code of the library itself is working. I just don't know anymore where to look for it.

Comment: Why would replacing `getResources()` with `context.getResources()` change anything? An Activity already is a Context, so there is no point in grabbing some Context object.

Comment: Sorry, i was looking at two questions at the same time, my mistake.